# Godot: detect if a pressed mouse is above button

Tags: button, collision, detection, godot

this is one of those issues where I believe there must be an incredibly simple way to do it and I still can't figure it out. Is there any way to figure out if my mouse (or finger on a touchscreen) is above a Button (any Button-Node) or not while it's being held pressed? Maybe something like "self global position"...? Something that immediately recognizes when leaving or entering the area while being held down.

The problem is that func _on_Button_mouse_exited(): does only fire at release but not at the moment of exiting. It works with CollisionShape2D, but obviously not with Buttons. I want it to emit a Signal the moment my finger slips off the Button.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First of all register input events to know if **mouse button is pressed or released**.

```
var pressed = false

func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT:
        pressed = event.pressed
```

Another way to check mouse button state is to add an *Action* to *Input Map* (in *Project Settings*) and add *Mouse Button* to the *Action*s keys list. Then you can check it with

```
var pressed = Input.is_action_pressed("MyMouseCliskAction")
```

---

Second, connect a callback to register **`mouse_entered`** and **`mouse_exited`** signals of the `Button` node.

```
var mouseIsOverButton = false

...
    button.connect("mouse_entered", self, "_on_mouse_entered")
    button.connect("mouse_exited", self, "_on_mouse_exited")
...

func _on_mouse_entered():
    mouseIsOverButton = true
func _on_mouse_exited():
    mouseIsOverButton = false
```

The described problem with `mouse_exited` signal happens only if mouse button was pressed inside the button area and not released until cursor leaves the button area. `is_hovered()` may be a more convenient way to check it for Button controls, but it is just a shortcut for the code above and has the same described problem.

If you want to overcome the issue you can use `CanvasItem.get_local_mouse_position()` (or `get_global_mouse_position()`) methods of the `Button` node and then just manually check if the position is within button's rect:

```
var pos = button.get_local_mouse_position()
var rect = Rect2(button.rect_position, button.rect_size)
var mouseIsOverButton = rect.has_point(pos)
```

Comment: Thank you Oliort, this is exactly the issue and a great way how to approach it.

get_rect().has_point(event.position) seems to be another go into that direction.

Comment: @pferft still to use `event.position` you need some sort of mouse event which will be triggered when the border is crossed. AFAIK `mouse_exited` event still won't be useful here because of the described behaviour - it just won't be triggered in time. Did you find any other way to get notified exactly at the moment of cursor leaving the button area?

Comment: So this here seems to do the trick:

`extends Button

class_name AbortableButton

var mouse_is_down = false
var has_aborted = false

signal abort

func _on_Button_gui_input(event: InputEvent):
 if event.is_action_pressed("lclick"):
  mouse_is_down = true
  has_aborted = false
 elif event.is_action_released("lclick"):
  mouse_is_down = false
 if mouse_is_down and event is InputEventMouseMotion:
  if not get_global_rect().has_point(get_global_mouse_position()) and not has_aborted:
   emit_signal("abort")
   has_aborted = true

func _on_Button_abort():
 print('Abort!')`